# Unwanted sliver of space to right of banner/webpage in iOS 7

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, css

Only in the Contact page of my site, there is a sliver of space to the right of the banner/webpage and it only shows up on my iPhone (I haven't checked any other mobile devices). The sliver doesn't show up when viewing my site on my Macbook Pro using Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. The other webpages are fine, even on my iPhone, so I'm thinking it has to do with the social media buttons or mailing list form. I checked my CSS and couldn't readily find a problem. I tried putting divs around the buttons/form and making the width less than 100% but that didn't seem to work, unless I am doing it incorrectly.

It wouldn't be such a horrible problem except that when I turn my phone from portrait to landscape, the page gets huge and doesn't scale to fit in the frame of the screen. This doesn't happen with any of the other pages so I'm assuming it has to do with that sliver on the right.

http://therevolution.jmoon.net/contact.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is adding the following to line 83 for the fb-like-box:

```
style="max-width: 90%; overflow: hidden;"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `displat:inline` in `@media only screen and (min-width: 481px)` and set `display:block` like this:

layour.css line : 129

```
#navigation ul li {
display: block;
margin-right: 1.5%;
margin-left: 1.5%;
border: 1px solid #33C;
background-color: #F2F2FF;
padding-top: 0.3em;
padding-right: 0.6em;
padding-bottom: 0.3em;
padding-left: 0.6em;
}
```

Comment: That makes my nav buttons stack on top of each other. And I don't think that is the problem because my other webpages use the same css, display: block for #navigation ul li, and there is no sliver to the right of those webpages.